# Where can I find this text from Midrash Tanhuma?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, midrash

Rabbi Nathan Lopes Cardozo discusses Jesus association with Balaam and offers the following text from the uncensored Midrash Tanhumah :

“Bilaam foresaw that a man born from a woman would arise and would proclaim himself a God.”  Therefore, Bilaam’s voice was given the power to inform the gentiles: “Do not go astray after this man, God is not a man, and if he (this man) says he is God, he is lying.”

Source:

https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/bilaam-jesus-and-the-jewish-tradition/

Where can I find this text?

Comment: That seems to be a confusion of two medrashim together (see https://www.google.co.il/books/edition/%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A9_%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%90%D7%92%D7%93%D7%94/_jpAAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%D7%91%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%9D+%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95&pg=PA14&printsec=frontcover&bshm=rime/1)